# OS X Mac and writing a twain scanning application

Tags: objective-c, macos, twain, scanning

Can someone point me to the correct place to start development of a twain scanning appliation for the MAC osx. I have done some simple objective c development in the past, but nothing interfacing with a device.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about Objective-C and TWAIN on the Mac, [this page](http://twain.org/mac.shtm) on the twain.org site has a DMG you can download which contains a sample project called TWAINClientCocoa.

It's from 2002 or something so it requires a little finagling to get it to load and build (rename the .pbproj folder to be a .xcode folder so it will open in Xcode and then do an "upgrade" when you're in Xcode) but it works (just tried it last week) and should give you a good starting point. It relies on the concept of the TWAIN source providing its on GUI but that's something you could modify.

Answer (score 0):

If someone if still interested in this, I have just written a TWAIN client on macOS for my application. [This documentation](https://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/TWAIN-2.2-Spec.pdf) is quite helpful.

The main problem doing this today is that the `PicHandle` returned by native transfer mode requires some deprecated functions to operate on. On my system (10.13) I can workaround this by making up the headers for those functions but they might be removed totally some time in the future. It's probably worth trying to use memory transfer mode which is more complex.